# Android Studio show this error: adb: could not initialize Winsock: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. (11003)

Tags: android, windows, android-studio

I am getting error in android studio.When i click on run  icon then Select Deployment target is showing nothing.And this is giving error.I tried many solution. But i didn't get any solution.I am finding solution from last two days.I uninstalled android studio.After that this is showing same error.When i use `adb kill-server`then this is showing `error: adb: could not initialize Winsock: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. (11003)`this error.Anyone Please help me.

**This is error:**

```
 17:02:40 This application has requested the Runtime to terminate it in an unusual way.
17:02:40 Please contact the application's support team for more information.
17:02:42 error: adb: could not initialize Winsock: A non-recoverable error occurred during a database lookup. (11003)
17:02:42 'C:\Users\IQS-9\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools\adb.exe,start-server' failed -- run manually if necessary
```

Comment: I think this is window problem..https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/288133/error-message-unable-to-initialize-windows-sockets-interface...if anyone has any solution tell me.

Answer (score 0):

I din't get any solution from anywhere.I reinstalled android studio 3 times.But it was giving same error.So i had no any solution for this problem.Finally I uninstall my windows after that my android studio is working well.